# Iterate list in drools

Tags: java, drools

I'm new to Drools and want to use it to iterate over a list of items and compare the item at index 1 with the item at index 0, the item at index 2 with the item at index 1 and so on.

Is there a way to specify this is a DRL file?
My DRL file so far is

```
import java.util.ArrayList

dialect  "mvel"

rule "Rule"
    when
        $client: Client()
        $activity: Activity(name == "Walking")
        $measurements: ArrayList()
    then
        ...
end
```

Or should I just write Java code in the `then` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't realy understand what you mean to do, but if you need to mangage collection you should see what you can do with the "from accumulate" function that enables you to instanciate collections in the predicate section.
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html 5.8.3.6.4.1